# XML from database, through DataSet, into XSLT processor

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, dataset

**TL;DR**

> Using a `DataSet`, I'm trying to pass `XML` (that is generated by a stored procedure, and returned as a single column) into an `XSLT` processor.  The `DataSet` is also populated with normal data generated by other stored procedures.  I cannot work out how to stop the DataSet encoding the `XML`, or how to get the `XSLT` processor to work with encoded `XML`

**Details**

In my ASP.NET 4.0 project, I am generating a `DataSet` object using an `.xsd` file.

This `DataSet` is being populated by multiple stored procedures from the database, one of which is returning quite complex `XML` as a column.

The result of `DataSet.GetXml()` is being passed to an `XSLT 1.0` processor (`XslCompiledTransform`).

**The problem is**, the `XML` that is returned from the stored procedure is being encoded, so the `XML` that the `XSLT` receives looks something like this..

*These are purely examples, and not necessarily exactly what would be produced*

```
<MyInformationDS>
  <simple><this/><that/><other/><simple>
  <complex>&lt;data&gt;&lt;item/&gt;&lt;/data&gt;</complex>
</MYInformationDS>
```

Where `<simple>` would be the result of `SELECT [THIS], [THAT], [OTHER] FROM [MYTABLE]`
And `<complex>` would be the result of `SELECT CAST('<data><item/><data>' AS XML)`

**I need the contents of `<complex>` to be un-encoded `XML`, or figure out how to make the `XSLT` processor handle encoded `XML`**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8711993/930393) suggests doing an `Server.HTMLDecode(DataSet.GetXml())`, but that has a major downside.  If `<simple>` contains encoded text (for example `<simple><this>cat &amp; dog</this><simple>`) then the decoded version becomes invalid XML.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5787916/930393) makes it pretty clear that I am not able to get XSLT 1.0 to process the encoded `XML` - so that's a dead-end.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392792/930393) says that it is not possible to force the `DataSet` to use `<![CDATA[..]]>>` which was one of the ideas I was thinking of.

Otherwise I'm stuck, and the time I spent writing the XML generation in the stored procedure will be completely wasted.

Any ideas??

Comment: If you don't need to manipulate the contents of the encoded part in XSLT as nodes, you can XSLT transform it as `<output type="text"/>` which will decode the angle brackets in the output.

Comment: Thanks @helderdarocha. I'm sure if my question is clear, but my ultimate aim is to be able to use the XPATH of `/MyInformationDS/complex/data/item` (using the example XML in my question).  I'm not sure what you're suggesting would acheive that